# Object only available in if statement in Obj - C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

probably an easy question...I'm a beginner programmer, so bear with me :)
I've made my first 'real' iPhone app that draws cards from a deck until a Joker is drawn, then the game is over.

So far, so good and it all works, except I have to use a work-around which I really hate.
My Deck object is only available where I declare it, which seems normal but yet irritating.

Basically, I have to make an entire new deck every time the user hits the "Draw Card" button...

```
- (IBAction)drawCard:(id)sender {
    Deck *deck = [[Deck alloc]init];
    deck.generate;
    unsigned int randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(deck.deckArray.count);
    Card *topCard = [deck.deckArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex - 1];
    if (topCard.value == 11) {
        NSString *cardInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You drew a Jack of %@", topCard.suit];
        self.cardDrawn.text = cardInfo;
    }else if (topCard.value == 12) {
        NSString *cardInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You drew a Queen of %@", topCard.suit];
        self.cardDrawn.text = cardInfo;
    }else if (topCard.value == 13) {
        NSString *cardInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You drew a King of %@", topCard.suit];
        self.cardDrawn.text = cardInfo;
    }else {
        NSString *cardInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You drew a %d of %@", topCard.value, topCard.suit];
        self.cardDrawn.text = cardInfo;
    }
    [deck removeCard];
    if (topCard.value == 14) {
        self.cardDrawn.text = @"You drew the Joker Bomb!";
        //Destroy deck
        deck = nil;
        [drawCard setEnabled:NO];
        [playAgain setEnabled:YES];
        [playAgain setHidden:NO];
    }

}


- (IBAction)playAgain:(id)sender {
    self.cardDrawn.text = nil;
    [drawCard setEnabled:YES];
    [playAgain setEnabled:NO];
    [playAgain setHidden:YES];
}

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self =[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        Deck *deck = [[Deck alloc]init];
        deck.generate;
    }
    return  self;
}

@end
```

If I take away `Deck *deck = [[Deck alloc]init];` in my `drawCard` button method, I get a bunch of errors and the app won't build. I've tried `@synthesize`ing the `deck` object, but that doesn't seem to work either, and I also tried making a pointer to `deck` but that was kind of useless and did not work as well.

I wanted to implement a label that would show how many cards are left in the deck, but that would be impossible since a new deck is being generated every time the user taps `drawCard`.

Sorry if this is a stupid question & thanks!

Comment: You need to make `deck` an instance variable, not one that is declared inside a method.

Comment: Just add a property to your class! `@property (nonatomic, strong) Deck *deck`

Comment: `[deck.deckArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex - 1];` will crash if randomIndex is 0. Do something like: `Card *topCard; if (deck.deckArray.count == 0) { topCard = nil } else if (deck.deckArray.count == 1) { topCard = [deck.deckArray firstObject]; } else { unsigned int randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(deck.deckArray.count - 1); topCard = [deck.deckArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex]; }`

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code. First of all what does "deck.generate;" do? That's not a valid Objective-C syntax.

The other thing is that you're realocating a deck everytime the drawCard method is called. Instead of using:

```
Deck *deck = [[Deck alloc]init];
```

You could declare Deck as an instance variable inside your interface and change the line above with:

```
deck = [Deck new];
```

Comment: It's valid, but poor form, to call a parameter-less method with dot syntax.

Comment: Didn't knew that. Thanks @JoshCaswell !

Comment: You mean _property_. If he'd use an _instance variable_, he'd be assigning `deck = [[Deck alloc] init];` instead of `self.deck = [[Deck alloc] init];`

Comment: Correct, misspelled it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ViewControllerTheOPDidntProvideANameFor ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) Deck *deck;
@end

@implementation ViewControllerTheOPDidntProvideANameFor

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self =[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    self.deck = [[Deck alloc]init];
    [self.deck generate];
    return  self;
}

@end
```

Comment: When you've got a `UIViewController`, the best place for initializing things is usually `viewDidLoad`. `initWithNibName:bundle:` is not called when your view controller is _inside_ another NIB, in that case `initWithCoder:` is called.

Comment: @DarkDust Noted, there are many places that deck could be instantiated. Personally, I'm a fan of the "common init" method or lazy loading. I wouldn't want to generalize and declare a "best" location.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.h` file, declare something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Deck *deck;
```

Then, in your `.m` file, initialize the deck (most likely in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`) using something like this:

```
self.deck = [[Deck alloc] init];
```

Then, you'll be able to use the same `deck` property using `self.deck` like this:

```
[self.deck generate]; //Good practice to use brackets instead of dot notation for function calls in Objective-C since dot operators indicate properties
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Per `DarkDust`'s remark, you can use an instance variable as well:

```
//.h    
@interface YourViewControllerName : UIViewController {

    Deck *deck;
}

//.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Initialize the deck
    deck = [[Deck alloc] init];
}
```

Your deck will then be accessible using `deck`.

Comment: Why assign to the backing variable and then access the property? If you're using a property instead of an instance variable (which I consider to be a bad habit), then you should be consistent and only access the property unless there's a good reason to access the backing variable.

Comment: Sorry, typo - I think I fixed it. In your opinion, what's the upside to using an instance variable versus a property?

Comment: An instance variable is tiny bit faster, but that's nothing you'll notice in real life. For me, it's about whether information is _private to your object_ or _public_. For example, does your code break horribly when a different object suddenly assigns a new `Deck` instance? Then you don't want it to be a public property. You can make the property "private" by defining it in your `.m` file instead, but unless you're not using ARC or you want KVO, there'd be no advantage to using a property.